# mysql gem for rails not getting installed on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

sony@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysql-ruby
sony@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: `mysql` gem has been inactive for the past 2 years. I recommend you to use postgresql instead - https://rubygems.org/gems/pg

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql
```